# TSQL SELECT CASE & change second column value

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I need to change the status of `ColumnB` depending on the value of `ColumnA`.  Something like pseudocode:

```
CASE WHEN ColumnA = 'True' THEN ColumnB = 'Alert' ELSE ColumnB
```

I am using Azure SQL Server.

Comment: why don't you try your pseudo-code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pseudo code actually seems quite right. Just drop the assignment to `ColumnB` and add an `end`:

```
SELECT ColumnA, 
       CASE WHEN ColumnA = 'True' THEN 'Alert' ELSE ColumnB END
FROM   MyTable
```

Also, note you can use a slightly neater syntax (although it's a matter of taste, mostly), since all (of the one) conditions you have are on the same expression:

```
SELECT ColumnA, 
       CASE ColumnA WHEN 'True' THEN 'Alert' ELSE ColumnB END
FROM   MyTable
```

Comment: Or maybe it should be an update query? `update your_table set ColumnB = 'Alert' where ColumnA = 'True'` The wording _need to change_ might imply that

Comment: I think I failed to clearly articulate the needs.  What I mean to say is:
 if ColumnA = 'True' THEN SET ColumnB VALUE = 'Alert' ELSE dont change ColumnB

Answer (score 2):

Based on your provided example, I don't think you even need a `case` statement.  A simple `update` will work just fine.

```
update YourTable
   set ColumnB = 'Alert'
 where ColumnA = 'True'
```

If, on the other hand, you are actually updating other columns at the same time based on other conditions, which prevents you from inserting the `where ColumnA = 'True'` clause, then you can do it with the `case` statement this way:

```
update YourTable
   set ColumnB = case when ColumnA = 'True' then 'Alert' else ColumnB end,
       ColumnX = ...
  from YourTable
```

Comment: I am actually doing a select.

Comment: Ha. Your question sounded more like an `update` to me.  Now, if it's a `select`, what's wrong with `Mureinik`'s answer?  It looks good to me.

Comment: I got Mureinik's answer to work thank you sstan for your help as well.  Unfortunately I got my question downvoted, likely for admitted lack of clarity, and cannot choose it as the answer.  Thank you all for the help!

Comment: You should be able to mark his post as the correct answer, and you really should.  The downvotes on your question should not prevent you from doing that.

Comment: You are right on page refresh it worked.  Thanks all!